# not able to read post values

Tags: php

I have the following php code, post values are taken from a form-

```
<?php
$file="data.xml";
$test= new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true);
echo $_POST['question1'];
echo $test->easy->question[0]->key;
echo $test->easy->question[$_POST['question1']]->key;
```

Output: 0 3

I am able to get the output for `echo $_POST['question1'];` also for echo `$test->easy->question[0]->key[0];` . But not for `echo $test->easy->question[$_POST['question1']]->key[0];`

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $test->easy->question[intval($_POST['question1'])]->key;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['question1']` probably contains a string, `'0'`. This is not necessarily the same as the number zero (`0`).

Comment: PHP doesn't care if 0 is a string or an interger when looking in an array, they are the close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting your `$_POST['question1']` string into an `int` by doing something like this:

```
$_POST['question1'] = (int)$_POST['question1'];
```